# Slider under Transparent Image Layer - Responsive Layout

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I want to create a responsive slider which lies under a transparent png image. The slider is working fine under the image with the following code on desktop however fails the responsive test.

**CSS:**

```
.layer {
  width: 1920px;
  height: 725px;
  background: url('../images/edge-holders.png') no-repeat top center;
  position: relative;
  margin: 0px;
  z-index: 99;
  top: -760px;
}
```

**HTML:**

```
// Some Slider Code comes here
<div class="layer"></div>
```

In the css I tried @media to resize the image to fit the slider width & height however it did not work.

Here is the image of what I want to achieve

**Edits:**
Ref Link: http://sociomarker.com/websites/ps/

[image]

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**.  See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)